# How to add a delimiter at a particular position in Oracle

Tags: sql, regex, string, oracle

Hi I have a string like this

```
ABCDEFGH I want the output to be ABCDEF.GH
```

If it's a number like   1234567  then i want the output to be 12345.67

Basically i want the delimeter (.) before last 2 characters.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.1-en/string-functions.html ?

Comment: INSERT() Insert a substring at the specified position up to the specified number of characters

Comment: As @MarcB pointed out, string functions are your friend. You'll probably need `INSTR()` combined with a `LENGTH()`, `LEFT()`, `RIGHT()`, and `CONCAT()`.

Comment: Or what @Kabulan0lak said. Ha. Nice function...

Comment: @MarcB That link points to the MySQL documentation, whereas - if I'm not mistaken - the OP wants a solution for Oracle.

Comment: @frank: well, technically MySQL *IS* oracle these days... But yeah, it should've been for the oracle rdbms. yay oracle for making the urls very unclear.

Comment: @MarcB Yes, Oracle's URL scheme for its documentation is totally brain dead. And the fact that they don't mention the RDBMS on the page itself doesn't help, either. The only reliable indicator I've found so far is the version number in the URL - 5.1 for MySQL, 10.X / 11.X / 12.X for Oracle RDBMS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regular expressions for this:

```
with v_data(val) as (
  select '123456' from dual union all
  select 'abcdef' from dual union all
  select '678' from dual
)
select 
  val, 
  regexp_replace(val, '(\d+)(\d{2})', '\1.\2') 
from v_data
```

This matches

- one or more digits `(\d+)` (capturing them in group #1)
- followed by exactly two digits `(\d{2})` (capturing them in group #2)

and replaces this with the contents of group #1 followed by a `.` followed by the contents of group #2: `\1.\2`

Comment: Hi if its a alpha numeric string.? Also I want to add the delimiter.

Comment: @user2647888 Please update your question accordingly. Sample input and expected output would be ideal.